# API resolved without sending a response for /api/addproducts, this may result in stalled requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

API resolved without sending a response for /api/addproducts, this may result in stalled requests.

This is add product API  and below is my code for that API

I Have debugged it using the console . Below is my code I am struggling to find error but could not succeed to do so.

```
import Product from "../../models/Products"
import dbConnect from "../../middlewear/db"


export default async function handler (req, res){

    const {method}=req
    dbConnect()
    if(method==='POST'){
        try {
        let product=await  new Product(req.body)
        savedProduct=await product.save()
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "success" });
        
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).json({status:"Internal server error", message:error.message})

        }       
    }
        
    }
```

THIS IS a DATABASE Connection to NEXT JS application

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const MONGNODB_URL=process.env.MONGNODB_URL

if(!MONGNODB_URL){
    throw new Error(
        "Please define mongo URI inside .env.local"   )
}
let cashed=global.momgoose

if(!cashed){
    cashed=global.mongoose={conn:null,promise:null}
}

async function connectDB(){
    if(cashed.conn){
        return cashed.conn}
    
    if(!cashed.promise){
    const opts={
        bufferCommands:false
    }
    
    
    cashed.promise= await mongoose.connect(MONGNODB_URL,opts).then((mongoose)=>{
        return mongoose
})
    
}
cashed.conn=await cashed.promise
return cashed.conn
}

export default connectDB
```

Comment: You should add handling for non-POST requests too, and return a proper response for those.

Comment: I am unable to understand  if you could write the syntax, please

Comment: The solution you found is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

The problem got solved by following code

```
// Next.js API route support: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

import Product from "../../models/Products"
import dbConnect from "../../middlewear/db"


export default async function handler (req, res){

    const {method}=req
    dbConnect()
    if(method==='POST'){
   
        let product=await new Product(req.body)
        let savedProduct=await product.save()
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "success",savedProduct });
        
            
    }else{
        res.status(424).json({status:"Product not added"})    
    }    
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).